# Flutter Firebase Anonymous Authentification Sign-In Upon Opening

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I currently have an app which Sign's-In a User when a button is tapped by calling :

```
Future<void> anonymousSignIn(DocumentSnapshot<Object> document, context) async {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
  var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  var uid = user.uid;

  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(getSnackBar("Signed In"));
}
```

But I'd like the User to not have to press any button & instead be automatically Signed-In Anonymously when the App is Open - I'm not sure where to write that & how in my App

*Also I ultimately will want to allow the user to also Sign-In with e-mail or Google so before Sign-In Anonymously upon Opening it will have to check if the user was not already Signed-In with those methods*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by `await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously()` it in your `main()` function before `runApp()`, so now you will have a user logged when the app starts.

I don't think your second part makes a sense, you will either automatically sign in the user anonymously or give him the options you mentioned which require the **click** to trigger Google `oAuth` flow or pass his credentials for the mail login.

Comment: thks I upvoted but I'm pretty sure I need to use Sign-In inside a Future thought ?

Comment: Well yes, you will add the `async` modifier at your `main`.

Comment: ok thks - I wrote it inside Future main() async { } is it correct ?

Comment: You can remove the `Future` just `async` and `void main()` will do the trick.

Comment: I think I need the Future to call `await Firebase.initializeApp();` I'll keep just in case thank you : )

Answer (score 2):

```
Future main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
  var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  var uid = user.uid;

  runApp(child : App());

}
```

This is the *full solution* I ended up writing thanks to @esentis

---

*but I'm still wondering - how to check if user had not logged In with Google the last time it open the App*

*to log it in with Google Automatically without pressing button instead of Anonymously*

---

[esentis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12413404/esentis) suggested using **Shared Preferences** to store the last login State - I will try to post my code when I have implemented it

Comment: You will need to "persist" this information somehow and somewhere, maybe try using the https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences package to store the last sign in information.

Comment: i see - I thought Firebase_auth managed all of this & remembered that a user was Signed-In ?

Comment: Well it does, but if you sign your user anonymously, on the next login the user will still be anonymous. An anonymous user is still a valid user. If you sign in with Google, next time you open the app the user will still be signed on his Google account.

Comment: Oh i see so I have to save somehow in Shared Preferences that user had successfully logged into Google the last time & not logged out thank you 